# Get method Codeigniter Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Good day guys.I'm getting trouble of using pagination with GET method. here is the problem. here is my link first http://localhost/eshoppy/Search/?search=nike but when I click the next button the search variable becames http://localhost/eshoppy/Search/?search=nike/3 so there will be no result of nike/3. How can I escape the /3 from the search get variable?

Here's my code in my controller index

```
        $search = $this->input->get('search');
        $search_ses=array('search_ses'=>$search);
        $this->session->set_userdata($search_ses);
        $data['item_details'] = $this->Model_items->search_item_details(3,$start,$search);
        $config['first_url'] = 'Search/index/?search='.$search;
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Search/?search='.$search;
        $config['total_rows']= $this->Model_items->getSearch_count($search);
        $config['per_page']=3;
       $config['last_link'] = 'Last &raquo;';
       $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
       $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
       $config['next_link'] = 'Next &rarr;';
       $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
       $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
       $config['prev_link'] = '&larr; Previous';
       $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
       $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
       $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
       $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
       $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
       $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

My model

```
    function search_item_details($num,$start,$search)
    {
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('shop_items')
        ->like('shop_item_name',$search)
        ->where('shop_item_status',1)
        ->where('shop_item_stock_num >',0)
        ->order_by('shop_item_date_posted', 'DESC')
        ->order_by('shop_item_featured', 'DESC')
        ->limit($num,$offset)
        ->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
$search = $this->input->get('search'); 
//outputs 'nike/3'
```

you can easly do something like this

```
$search = $this->input->get('search'); 
$get = explode('/',$search); 
$search = $get[0];
//in this case 'nike'
```

Also if you need the '3' after nike, you can get it doing this

```
$number = $get[1];
```

You can check [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on PHP Manual